# Regularity of linear elliptic equations: from L^p to Holder estimate

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\phi$ (vanishing as $|x|$ goes to infinity) satisfy
\begin{equation*}
-\Delta\phi-\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^2}\phi = g,\quad \text{in}\quad \mathbb{R}^N
\end{equation*}
If $g$ satisfies $ g\in C(\mathbb{R}^N) $ satisfies
$$ |g(x)|\leq \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{N+2}}, $$
then can one obtain that $\phi\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N) $?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea. There are several papers told that, by local elliptic estimate, one can get $ \|\phi\|_{W^{2,q}B(0,1)}+ \|\phi\|_{L^{\infty}B(0,1)}\leq \| (1+|x|^2)^{N+2}g \|_{\infty}$. I do not know how to precedu the progress.